# deployment error due to richfaces lagger

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

I have created a web application using JSF and spring in which I used primefaces and richfaces.After then I removed the richfaces jar files from /lib of my project and It is working fine.Now then I created the WAR file and when I tried to deploy that file (on GlassFish server) then it was unable to deploy and it throws this exception

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.richfaces.webapp.RichFacesServletsInitializer could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/richfaces/log/RichfacesLogger. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Now I am unable to understand why this is showing the exception
**NOTE:** For afe checking , I cleaned my project , then rebuild again and then created war but still running from this issue.

Comment: What RichFaces version do you use and what dependencies do you have on your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

What does your server.log say? And looking into the error, it seems like, there are still references for richfaces.

Comment: this is not an answer, please consider using the comments to get more clarity of the question...

Comment: @dakait yes, I would surely like to do that but I couldn't see comment button anywhere.... I read faq as well and they say there will be a small type comments but I really couldn't find that. I know this is an off topic answer but I would have to do it...

Comment: you require 50 rep points to be able to comment on questions, http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Comment: Yes, so what should I do in this case as I can not comment till then? Shouldn't I comment or answer the questions?

Comment: you can answer but dont post comments as answer